# Using Jest + TypeScript, how do I mock a static method used in another static method of a class being tested?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, dependencies, static-methods

I have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` that contain only static methods. One of the methods in `ClassA`, called `staticMethodA()`, calls a static method from `ClassB`, called `staticMethodB`.

```js
import { ClassB } from './classB'

export class ClassA {
    public static async staticMethodA() {
        return await ClassB.staticMethodB();
    }
}
```

While working on a unit test for `staticMethodA()`, I wanted to mock `staticMethodB()` to better isolate `staticMethodA()`. Following existing guidance online, I created the following test:

```js
    describe('staticMethodA', () => {
        let classA;

        const mockStaticMethodB = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}); //return dummy object

        beforeAll(() => {

            // Mocking ClassB
            jest.mock('../src/classB', () => () => ({

                ClassB: { 
                    staticMethodB: mockStaticMethodB
                }

            })}};

            // Importing ClassA after mocking ClassB so it references the mock
            classA = require('../src/classA');
        }

        it('should call mockStaticMethodB', async () => {

            //The object returned from require is an object containing ClassA
            const actual = await classA.ClassA.staticMethodA();

            expect(actual).toBe({}); // dummyObject
        }

        afterAll(() => {
            jest.unmock('../src/classB');
        });
    }
```

I get an error when staticMethodA calls staticMethodB that says that ClassB is undefined. When I set a breakpoint on `return await ClassB.staticMethodB();`, I see there's a variable called `classB_1` available but not `ClassB`.

I've tried some of the mock construction strategies found in the following resources, but all still resulted in `ClassB` being undefined:

- https://meticulous.ai/blog/mocking-a-javascript-class-with-jest-two-ways-to-make-it-easier/
- https://medium.com/@david-ting/jest-jest-typescript-mocking-static-method-42f420020a07
- https://www.linkedin.com/learning-login/share?account=88323306&forceAccount=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Flearning%2Fnode-js-testing-and-code-quality-14003857%2Fmocking-module-dependencies%3Ftrk%3Dshare_video_url%26shareId%3DvzQuLJXkT%252Byp2r6dSqXYIQ%253D%253D

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that would need changing in this case. I've tested this locally and it works.

```js
// classa.test.ts
import {ClassA} from '../classA';
// we are importing ClassB directly
// this will be the mocked version
import {ClassB} from '../classB';

// mock should be hoisted to the top of the module
jest.mock('../classB', () => {
    return {
        ClassB: {
            staticMethodB: jest.fn(),
        },
    };
});

describe('classA', () => {
    it('should call mockStaticMethodB', async () => {
        // since ClassB is a mock we can provide the return value for this test case only
        (ClassB.staticMethodB as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce(42);
        const actual = await ClassA.staticMethodA();

        // note that in both mock and here we are using 42 for comparison as it works with `expect().toBe()`
        // if we wanted to compare objects we would use `expect().toEqual()` instead
        expect(actual).toBe(42);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Anton Kastritskiy! Thanks for the response! I didn't mention above (I will update in a moment) but I'm using TypeScript. When I made the changes you suggested, I received an error that `ClassB.staticMethodB.mockReturnedValueOnce` is not a function.

Comment: Interesting. This is what the `as jest.Mock` was for. When trying this out I used typescript as well. when you cast something as `jest.Mock` does typescript recognise it as a mock?